# Create a documentSet using graph API - configuration

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I implemented with Graph API several calls to create a document set.
I followed the answer posted here concerning the possibility of creating a DocumentSet in SharePoint here : [Is it possible to create a project documentset using graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208013/is-it-possible-to-create-a-project-documentset-using-graph-api)

For this i followed those steps :

**1. Getting the library driveId :**

```
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/lists/${listId}?$expand=drive`
```

**2. Creating the folder:**

`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/${driveId}/root/children`

I have to pass an object:

```
{
    "name": ${nameOfTheFolder},
    "folder": {},
}
```

**3. Getting the Sharepoint itemId:**

**4. Updating the document library:**

```
`PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/lists/${listId}/items/${sharepointIds.listItemId}`
```

and passing a body:

```
{
  "contentType": {
    "id": "content-type-id-of-the-document-set"
  },
  "fields": {
    //whatever fields you want to set
  }
}
```

I have questions concerning the folder creation and the updating:
What is expected in the folder object ?

```
{
    "name": ${nameOfTheFolder},
    "folder": {},
}
```

Concerning the path step:

```
{
  "contentType": {
    "id": "content-type-id-of-the-document-set"
  },
  "fields": {
    //whatever fields you want to set
  }
}
```

I have several questions :

- Let's consider i have a document type called **invoices**. Which id is expected for document type id ?
- finally how do i pass the fields ? let's say i want to pass 3 fields : invoiceId, claimId, clientId.

Graph API is great but some more information would be helpful. thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have questions concerning the folder creation and the updating: What is expected in the folder object ?*

The folder object (sent as {}) is there to tell graph API that you are creating a folder and not a file. It is a [property of the drive item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/folder?view=graph-rest-1.0)

*Let's consider i have a document type called invoices. Which id is expected for document type id ?*
This is the id [contentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/contenttypeinfo?view=graph-rest-1.0) subfield of the [list item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) you are patching

*ally how do i pass the fields ? let's say i want to pass 3 fields : invoiceId, claimId, clientId.*

You just pass them with repective values like below. See [Update listItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
{
   "invoiceId": "value",
   "claimId": "value"
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One point I didn't express correctly was to know what id is expected here :

```
{
  "contentType": {
    "id": "content-type-id-of-the-document-set"
  },
  "fields": {
    //whatever fields you want to set
  }
}
```

I retrieved the different content types of my site by calling this kind of URL and check if the content type exists.

> [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/lists/${listId}/contentTypes](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/$%7BsiteId%7D/lists/$%7BlistId%7D/contentTypes)

From the result i retrieve in a Value object the id.
The id looks like this :

> 0x0120D5200082903AB771604546844DB2AC483D905B00E58445A7D..........

Answer (score 0):

In modern SharePoint, you can also get the Content Type ID from the UI by browsing to SharePoint Site > Site Settings > Site content types > `<ContentTypeName>` > Content Type ID.

[Content Type ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nh5e.png)

Not sure if this is easier than via graph, but it's another option at least.