# Create document set in Sharepoint with Graph API in a subfolder

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

I already implemented the creation of a document set at library root level. For this I used the following link: [Is it possible to create a project documentset using graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208013/is-it-possible-to-create-a-project-documentset-using-graph-api)

I follow the following steps :

1- Retrieve the document library's Drive Id:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/lists/${listId}?$expand=drive
```

2- Create the folder:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/${library.drive.id}/root/children
```

The body of the request is the following

```
{
  "name": ${folderName},
  "folder": {},
}
```

3- Get the folder's SharePoint item id:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/drives/${library.drive.id}/items/${folder.id}?expand=sharepointids
```

4- Update the item in the Document Library so that it updates to the desired Document Set:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/lists/${listId}/items/${sharepointIds.listItemId}
```

I do send the following body to the patch request:

```
{
  "contentType": {
    "id": "content-type-id-of-the-document-set"
  },
  "fields": {}
}
```

I'm looking now how to create a document set in a specific folder in Sharepoint.
For example, i want to create the following folder structure.
The documents folder is at the library root and I want to create a document set named billing.

```
documents
|_ billing
   |_ 2021
      |_11
        |_01
           |_ document1.pdf
           |_ document2.pdf
           |_ document3.pdf
        |_02
           ...
        |_03
           ...
        |_04
      |_10
      ...
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar but I'm a little behind you, haven't yet created the Document Set (almost there!), but *may I respectfully challenge your approach?*

I'm not sure it's a good idea to mix Folders and Document Sets, mainly because a Folder breaks the metadata flow, you could achieve the same results *just* using Document Sets.

I am assuming that your 'day' in the data structure above is your Document Set (containing document1.pdf, etc.) You might want to consider creating a 'Billing' Document Set and either specifically add a Date field to the Document Set metadata or, perhaps better still, just use the standard Created On metadata and then create Views suitably filtered/grouped/sorted on that date.

This way you can also create filtered views for 'Client' or 'Invoice' or 'Financial Year' or whatever.

As soon as your documents exist in a folder, you can no longer filter/sort/group etc., the document library based on metadata.

---

**FURTHER INFORMATION**

I am personally structuring my Sales document library thus:

- **Name:** *Opportunity*; **Content Type:** *Document Set*; **Metadata:** *Client Name, Client Address, Client Contact*
- **Name:** *Proposal*; **Content Type:** *Document*; **Metadata:** *Proposal ID, Version*
- **Name:** *Quote*; **Content Type:** *Document*; **Metadata:** *Quote ID, Version*

Etc...

This way the basic SharePoint view is a list of Opportunities (Document Sets), inside which are Proposals, Quotes etc., but I can also filter the view to just show Proposals (i.e. filter by Content Type), or search for a specific Proposal ID, or group by Client Name, then sort chronologically, or by Proposal ID etc.

I'm just saying that you get a lot more flexibility if you avoid using Folders entirely.

*p.s. I've been researching for days now how to create Document Sets with graph, it never occurred to me that it might be a two-step process i.e. create the folder, then patch its content type. Many thanks for your post!!*

Answer (score 0):

Just re-read your post and my assumption that the 'day' would be your document set was incorrect. In this case, there would be no benefit having a Document Set containing Folders because the moment a Folder exists in the Document Set, metadata flow stops, and the only reason (well, the main reason*) to use Document Sets in preference to Folders **is** that metadata flow.

**Document Sets also allow you to automatically create a set of documents based on defined templates.*

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answers above, In step 3 where you are supposed to get the SharePoint Item Id, you might run into issues retrieving the sharepointid. This is caused by using the query parameter ?expand=sharepointids. To get the sharepoinid, simply change the expand to select.

for example, the previous implementation that can cause error:

```
    GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/drives/${library.drive.id}/items/${folder.id}?expand=sharepointids
```

.

New implementation:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/${siteId}/drives/${library.drive.id}/items/${folder.id}.Request().Select("sharepointIds");
```